# jquery ui sortable append

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

here is my jquery code as it stands.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn1').click(function() {
   $("ol").append("<li>"+$("#txt1").val()+"</li>");
   $("#txt1").val("").focus();
   $('li').addClass('block2');
   $('li').click(function() {
     $(this).hide(500, function() {
     $(this).remove('li');
   });
 });
});
});
```

Its basically a blank todo list, however when you enter in text and click the button, it appends to the list. I'm looking for code to re-arrange the items in the list 'that have been appended'. All the examples for jquery-ui for sort-able or drop-able, all have 'li' elements already in place in the HTML so this will not work in my code.

How do I add to my jquery code to make a user entered list rearrangable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by recalling `sortable()` inside the first `.click()`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $("ol").append("<li>"+$("#txt1").val()+"</li>");
        $("#txt1").val("").focus();
        $('li').addClass('block2');
        $('ol').sortable();
        $('li').click(function() {
            $(this).hide(500, function() {
            $(this).remove('li');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I must be missing code elsewhere, this did not work. I added your idea and included the cdn link to jquery-ui on my html :(. Oh and it also broke my last click function where it hides and removes the selected 'li' element.

Comment: You were completely right! I moved my html script, cleaned up some bad code and retried your simple idea and BAM, it worked :) Thank you very much, your making this newb better @ coding!!